# How to convert a GridView string column to an integer or double column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

Here is a string column in my GridView:

```
Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)
```

I tried to convert it to double column:

```
Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)
```

also tried this:

```
double x = double.Parse(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)
```

but always throws exception: "Input string was not in a correct format"

the code only runs if I type this way `Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)`

but there are number values in it and need to get values as a number not a string...

I am using bound field and template field in GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width ="219px" Height="258px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="k1" HeaderText="k1" />
                        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="k2" HeaderText="k2" />

                        <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Rank1" HeaderText="Rank1">


            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>


                        </asp:TemplateField>



                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the Rank Button code:

protected void Rank_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        SortedDictionary<double, int> MyRank = new SortedDictionary<double, int>();

        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (Convert.ToDouble(gRow.Cells[0].Text) != 0)
            {

                double score = Convert.ToDouble(gRow.Cells[0].Text);
                while (MyRank.ContainsKey(score))
                    score += 0.00001;

                MyRank.Add(score, gRow.RowIndex);

                //MyRank.Add(Convert.ToDouble(gRow.Cells[0].Text), gRow.RowIndex);

                gRow.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
            }
        }


        

        

        for (int irS = 0; irS < GridView1.Rows.Count; irS++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[irS].Cells[0].Text) > 0)
            {

                ir = ir + 1;

            }
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<double, int> OneRank in MyRank)
        {


            GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value];
            Label lRank = (Label)gRow.FindControl("lblRank");
            lRank.Text = (ir + 1).ToString();
            ir--;

        }
```

This is successfully shows ranking in the template field how you showed me in your example, but:

when template filed uploads with ranking numbers which is this column in Gridview: `Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)`  and I want to access it:

```
 for (int t = 0; t < GridView1.Rows.Count; t++)
            {
   
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text) < 5 )
                        {
                            labelX.Text = "message";
                        }
                     }
```

it throws exeption : input format is not in correct format...

If I use
`Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)`
format is does not throw exception but can`t access the integeres(ranking numbers), if I try to convert it into` Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text)`

it throws the exception....

Comment: is the GV column a templated column, or a default "databound" column? For databound columns, then you use the cells[] collection. However, for a templated column, then you have to use find control. it would take the readers here 18 seconds to figure this out had you provided the markup of the GV.  We are not sitting at your keyboard  and we can't see your markup. Beyond difficult for us here to debug in a dark room with the lights turned off.  If  you place a break-point on that line, what value does cell 2 have??

Comment: I reedited the post.. The ranking works, in the template field it puts the ranking values how you showed it in your tutorial but the problem is I can not access the values when I need it cause it stores as a type of string value and not an integer value...

Comment: How I see and tried debugging  the value of:   (GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text) is ""and it is a string type....

Comment: Ok, so is the cell supposed to be blank? and if yes, then we need to take that into account for the ranking. I would assume a reasonble course of action would be to assume a value of 0 for the blank ones? As noted, we should move this rank code to WHEN we fill the gv with data - and operate against the data. That way, we don't have to deal with string conversions, and we are dealing with strong typed data - this would result in not only less code, but far more robust code. So, while we have a working proof of concept code, we can do much better. I'll post example code tonight (busy day).

Comment: VALUE was a qoute: "" DATA TYPE: string. Thanks for helping...

Comment: You can't use cells collection for templated columns, you MUST use find control. So, unless the actual value that we attempting to rank was blank (and you not mentioned this can be the case), then we should not have to worry. You NOT explained now after filling out the rank what you attempting to do with the rank value (such as perhaps conditional color the column to display a given color). As I stated, I posted new code that does NOT care if duplicate ranks exist, and we dumped the "while" loop. and your sample data did not really reflect real world data. What do you want to do with rank?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the string value in the cell is not a valid representation of a int, the Parse method will throw a FormatException.
can you provide us with the value that you are trying to convert?

Try using the TryParse method instead.

````
var cellValue = GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text;

if (Int32.TryParse(cellValue, out int intValue))
{
    // If the conversion was successful, use the int value.
    Console.WriteLine(intValue);
}
else
{
    // If the conversion was not successful, handle the error.
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid number format.");
} ```
````

Comment: I want to convert from string to integer. The GridView column shows integer values/numbers but those are somehow in string form and can`t get the integer values

Comment: provide us the value ```GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text``` when it throws the format exception. Is the string value formatted? for example "$2"? if yes, You can try to strim out the char characters using a regular expression, and then try to convert.

Comment: How I know it is a string formatted column what regular expression  to use extract the integer??

Comment: To know the string is formatted, you can see the value of GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text in the debug mode. put a breakpoint before the line that throws an exception.

Comment: To extract only number with regex try this: ```string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");``` input is your formatted string

Comment: it doesn`t work for me... in column Rank1 template fields where is a label embed where are numbers but not in a expected from... those numbers are coming from here: foreach (KeyValuePair<double, int> OneRank in MyRank)
        {


            GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value];
            Label lRank = (Label)gRow.FindControl("lblRank");
            lRank.Text = (ir + 1).ToString();
            ir--;

        }   ..... ir is an integer in  a control label embed in Rank1 template field...

Answer (score 0):

So, lets MAJOR back up the truck here. We don't have blank values for rank!!

I mean, right off the bat, alarm bells should be going off here in a HUGE HUGE way!!

```
We see values in the gv for rank.
We observe the code is setting up rank
```

AND THEN the whole thing is crashing in a MASSIVE ball of flames, since you now seeing "" or empty for the rank. Now we have a bunch of people offing code HOW to deal with blank values WHEN we NEVER are to have blanks!!!

Talk about running down the wrong path!!!

The issue to solve here NOT how to deal with blanks, but discover WHY are we seeing a blank value!!!

Perhaps I am really wasting my time here. I FLAT OUT CRYSTRAL CLEAR stated in my last post this:

```
for databound columns, you use cells[] to get the value.
for templated columns, you have to use find control.
```

Now, WHY ARE YOU NOT reading my advice here?

so, trying to pull/use/get/grab the rank value from the cells[] collection WILL NEVER work!!!

if the value from the gv row is in a template column, then we can NOT use the cells collection.

However, lets not use the gv to deal with ranking anyway. It far better to simple avoid this issue.

so, lets assume this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" HeaderStyle-Width="120" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Night Rate" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Rank by (Price)">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text = '<%# Eval("Rank") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And thus we have this code now:

Note HOW we are doing the ranking on the data, and NOT the GV.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");

        // now, lets rank the DATA and NOT the GV
        rstData.Columns.Add("Rank", typeof(int));

        var Ranks = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, int>>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow OneRow in rstData.Rows)
        {
            decimal Price = (decimal)OneRow["Price"];
            Ranks.Add(new KeyValuePair<decimal, int>(Price, i));
            i++;    
        }

        Ranks = Ranks.OrderBy(o => o.Key).ToList(); // sort the list
        decimal LastValue = -1;
        int Rank = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<decimal, int> OneRank in Ranks)
        {
            if (LastValue != OneRank.Key)
                Rank++;
            rstData.Rows[OneRank.Value]["Rank"] = Rank;
            LastValue = OneRank.Key;
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

So, we now see this:

[image]

So, note how it was MUCH better to add a "Rank" colum to the data table.

we then run our rank code against the data, and NOT the GV.

Now, say for some reason that we want say the first 5 to be a light blue, and then anything >5 to be a darker blue.

Well, we then would use the row data bound event, and we can do this, and ONCE again, we don't even have to use the gv data, but we can use + enjoy the data row value used here. (so, no messy type conversions required!!!).

So, say this code:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView OneDataRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            // we can use cells colleciton to fomrat background,
            GridViewRow OneGridRow = e.Row;
            if ((int)OneDataRow["Rank"] <= 5)
                OneGridRow.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SkyBlue;
            else
                OneGridRow.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
        }
    }
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

So the real moral of the story here?

As I stated, we want to try and work with the data, and NOT against the GV.

However, for the sake of learning, lets PULL the rank value from the GV, and in above, the rank value is a templated column, NOT a databound column.

So, remember that rule:

```
databound columns = cells
tempatled column = we must use find control.
```

So, our row data bound event to fomrat the column would now become this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label MyLableRank = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblRank");
            // we can use cells colleciton to fomrat background,
            int MyRank = Convert.ToInt32(MyLableRank.Text);
            if (MyRank  <= 5)
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SkyBlue;
            else
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
        }
    }
```

so, if we are/were/going to/think about/will/entertain the idea of grabbing the value from the gv row? Then above shows how we do this, since as noted, ANY AND ALL templated columns require us to use find control for each row, grab the control type, and then pull the value from the control - we can't use cells collection anymore for such templated columns.

Comment: The problem is that I have no real data storage cause my data source is not a database but a string[] that`s why I do calculations in GridView and wanted to do ranking in a GridView

Comment: Your data source for the GV can't be a "string". it might be a sqldata source dropped into the markup. You thus can still assign that sql datasource to a data table, and then once again, the code is as per the data table example. You then assign table to gv. Thus little changes. At the end of the day, and since the dawn of computers one will find 9 out 10 times, manipulation at data level is MUCH better then at the UI level (it is a lesson you need to learn to survive in the computer industry). Regardless, you have options here and great example code to achieve this goal either way

Comment: I am using splitted strings coming from textbox and dropping it in Gridview not using sql in this project..... I made a breakpoint with your previous  tutorial using FindControl() and the value show not blank value, so for GridView1.Rows[t].FindControl("lblRank") it says value => {Text="1"}    so there is a number in gridview I just need to change something in template field or lblRank lable and could take out that number is there any method??

Comment: In this part need some change foreach (KeyValuePair<double, int> OneRank in MyRank)
            {


                GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value];
                Label lRank = (Label)gRow.FindControl("lblRank");
                lRank.Text = (ir + 1).ToString();
                ir--;

            }   cause this makes one integer into a string and kept as a string....

Comment: You NOT sending a string to a GV, you are no doubt sending the string parsed out to a list or even a datatable (which is a option you have). Take a look at this recent post of mine - I take files from a folder, and send to a data table (no database involved at all). So, doubtful you sending strings to a gv, you sending strings to some kind of structure or "list" BEFORE you send to the GV. And that structure/list is where you should do the ranking (since working against data source is better). However, as noted, the posted code works just fine anyway if you choose to process against the gv.

Comment: so, you can send those strings to a data table - no database required.  But, you "must" have some type of list or structuote you send to the gv. So, nothing stopping you from sending the strings to a table object, and then binding to gv. See this recent post of mine where this is exaclty what I am doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74765605/order-of-processing-methods/74766189?noredirect=1#comment131967011_74766189

Comment: I managed to solve the problem: I tried this method and reedited your code example and used Cell collection:  GridViewRow gRow = GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value];     
                Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value].Cells[2].Text += ir + 1);
                ir--;    
                Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value].Cells[2].Text);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value].Cells[2].Text) < 11)
                {TextBox2.Text ="message...."
                }   this way can get the integer ranking...

Comment: The concpets and ideas outlined are probably more valuable here. As noted, Better to send that string data to a stucuture of some type, process it, and THEN send to the GV. However, it looks like you have it working. It looks a bit messay, but if it works then it works.

Comment: It works but still have a problem: When I access the rankings for example I ask the top 10 rankings it sends to the textbox in reversed order but not in order of rows after this code:  if (Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value].Cells[2].Text) < 11)     So showing instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 it shows 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1. If you know please tell me how to access rankings after order of GridView rows

Comment: It sends strings by order of OneRank.Value and not by order of GridView rows

Answer (score 0):

```
var lblRank = (Label)GridView1.Rows[t].FindControl("lblRank");
int i = 0;
int.TryParse(lblRank.Text, out i);
```

You are doing this:

```
<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Rank1" HeaderText="Rank1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can try to get the text like this:

```
string cellText = GridView1.Rows[t].Cells[2].Text;
```

You'll that, it's empty, blank. So, which means, you're actually converting a blank string into number.

By the way, you code seems a bit mis-alignment, use Ctrl+K+D to align your code.