# order of processing methods

Tags: html, asp.net, button, event-handling

I display 16 of 147 images in a grid.  when the user presses "next", I would like the page number to increment and the next 16 images to display.

To do this, I have a "next" button at the bottom (and prev, of course). I've added the following markup to the html:

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNext" Text="Next"   OnClick="btnNext_Click" CommandName="btnNextCmd"  oncommand="btnNext_Command" />

I've placed the two event handlers in the code behind and added a break point to each handler, as well as to the Page_Load method.

The catch is that the Page_Load is executed before either of the button event handlers.  I need to determine if the "Next" button was pressed, BEFORE the Page_Load executes, since this determines which 16 images to display.

Is there a way to determine if the "Next" button was clicked, without using an event handler?  I assume that calling the event handler from the Page_Load method would gum up the works, since .NET is going to call that handler after processing the Page_Load method.

Comment: Please post the code for your `Page_Load` event as well as your button event handlers. We need to see all the details in order to help.

Comment: Thank you.  I'v used the solution of the first responder.  I can't see the comments, so I don't know his name, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is page load determine this?

Move the code from the page load event that loads the pictures to the next and previous buttons.

Or, better yet, have the next/previous buttons call that routine to load the pictures. Since the dawn of time for asp.net, page load has ALWAYS fired before any other button code, and it fires each time.

Since page load has ALWAYS fired before everything else, then the goal here would not to be re-engineer the WHOLE WAY and WHOLE asp.net model, but in fact to write your code that conforms to how web forms work. I mean, it would not be fair to suggest that you are the first person in 20 years of this system to have that issue, are you?

the general code pattern is that we "often" do want some setup code, initialization code, and a boatload of code to ONLY run on the first "real" page load, and thus you write such code like this in page load:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    ' first time page load code goes here
    ' set starting image page list number
    ' set ending page image list number
    Call ImageLoad()
End If
```

So, now for next button, we have

```
 ' set start/end image numbers
 Call ImageLoad()
```

So, now, each time you click a button or ANY post-back occures on the page, the first time page load event will now not fire nor run.

In fact, for the last 200+ web pages I have coded out, EVERY SINGLE one of those pages has that all important if NotPostBack then run first time code in all of those pages.

In fact, you can't really even build a operational webforms page unless you do the above.

Say for example on page load, you run code to load up a combo box (dropdown list).

if you don't use a if Not is Post back stub in page load?

Then on page load (which as I noted RUNS EVERY TIME and RUNS BEFORE your button event stub?

Well, what will occur is by re-loading and re-binding the dropdown list, you now lose your dropdown settings, and your selection will be lost!!!

in fact, even for say setting up a few text boxes with some default values?

Again, we can use page load event, but ONLY code inside that Not post back stub can be used for setting up everything on the page. If we setup some defaults, and have it run each time? Then any entry into those text box(s) will be blown out, and over written each time. (by say some code that loads up default values for the user to edit).

Same goes for loading a grid or anything else. Once again, you REALY have to make sure you place code inside of that not post back stub on page load, since then you only re-load the grid or whatever on the REAL and TRUE first page load. After that occurs, then each additional button click etc. will re-run the page load event, but of course code inside of that "not" post back stub will not run!!!

So, place your setup code, your starting list of pictures to display inside of that "not" postback stub.

Then your next/previous buttons can work, and the code to load up, setup and load the first page of pictures will only ever run one time.

So, keep the above concept in mind.

That concept?

you really cannot build a functional working asp.net webform page by ignoring the above advice - it just the way they work, and thus you use the IsPostBack flag to control if that setup and startup code is a "one time" occurring, or in some cases, we do in fact WANT some code to run each time on page load.

so, just keep in mind that page load fires each and every time for ANY button click, and even a dropdown list with autopost-back will re-trigger the page load event.

But, armed with above knowledge, you not care, since we have a real and true first page load event, and that real and true first page load event is in fact the code you place in the page load event, but inside of that if/then Not post back stub.

## Edit: Working example of above

So, now, lets cobble together some working code based on above concept.

lets assume a folder with some images. (I have a junk folder of cut + paste images - lets just use that for this example).

So, I want to display some images on a page - next/previous buttons.

So, we will:

```
on our first REAL page load, pull files from folder
send files to a in memory data table (no database)
send those files to a list view (or grid view)
```

So, first up, we need markup to display a image. We can use grid view, or a repeater, or my favorate is listview (I like list view, since it supports a data pager for next/previous).

So, inside of our listview, we just cook up some markup for ONE picture, and thus it will "repeat" over and over.

So, I have this markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  Allowpaging="true" >
    <ItemTemplate>                   
        <div class="mybox">
            <div style="text-align:center;padding:2px 10px 2px 10px"  >
                <asp:Button ID="cmdMyView" runat="server" Text="View" 
                    CssClass="btn-info" style="float:right"
                    />
                <br />
                <h3><%# Eval("File") %></h3>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("FileAndPath") %>' Width="150"  />
                <br /> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

All I did was "create" a box and layout for one image.

In fact, the data pager markup is perhaps "more of a mess".

So, right below the above listview, I have this for the data pager:

```
    <br />
    <div style="clear:both;height:10px"></div>
    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="8" >
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField PreviousPageText=" <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i> Prev" 
                ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                ShowNextPageButton="false" ShowLastPageButton="false"
                ButtonCssClass="btn btn-default"   />

            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" 
                CurrentPageLabelCssClass="btn btn-primary disabled" 
                NumericButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" ButtonCount="10" 
                NextPageText="..." NextPreviousButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" />

            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField NextPageText=" Next <i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i> " 
                ShowNextPageButton="true"
                ShowPreviousPageButton="false" ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                ButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="false" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

(can't remember where I found above - but I use it over and over).

So, now our code. We read that folder of files, shove them into a "on the fly" table, and then send the table to the listview.

This code thus uses that VERY important real first page load (code inside of not a post back stub).

So, this:

```
Dim rstFiles As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadPictures()
        LoadGrid()
        ViewState("rstPics") = rstFiles
    Else
        rstFiles = ViewState("rstPics")
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadPictures()

    rstFiles.Columns.Add("File")
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("FileAndPath")
    rstFiles.Columns.Add("Created", GetType(DateTime))

    Dim sFolder As String = "~/Content/Pictures"
    Dim MyFolder As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(sFolder))

    Dim MyFileList() As FileInfo = MyFolder.GetFiles("*.*")

    For Each OneFile As FileInfo In MyFileList
        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstFiles.NewRow
        Debug.Print($"<{OneFile.Name}>")
        OneRow("File") = OneFile.Name
        OneRow("FileAndPath") = sFolder & "/" & OneFile.Name
        OneRow("Created") = OneFile.CreationTime.ToString("G")
        rstFiles.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Next


End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    ListView1.DataSource = rstFiles
    ListView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And for data pagaing, you need this event + code:

```
Protected Sub ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(sender As Object, e As PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs) Handles ListView1.PagePropertiesChanging

    DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
    LoadGrid()

End Sub
```

So, the result is now this:

[image]

but, we could replace above with a simple grid view, and say this markup:

A gridview, and pager tends to be less markup.

so, say this gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="40%"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CssClass="table" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="6" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="File" HeaderText="FirstName" ItemStyle-Width="230"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("FileAndPath") %>' Width="120"  />                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" 
                    CssClass="btn-info" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
     <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
</asp:GridView>
```

the code is near idential.

So, LoadGrid is now this:

```
Sub LoadGrid()

    GridView1.DataSource = rstFiles
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And pager event code is this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    Me.LoadGrid()

End Sub
```

and now we see/get this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help.  I haven't tried it, yet, but I can see where it makes sense.

Now, what makes you think I want to re-engineer how asp.net or the web at large works?

I merely wanted to know how it works, so I could tailor my code to suit.

Comment: My apologies if my suggesting was that you wanted to "change" how things work. My only goal was to in a very strong way point out how that page load concept (not post back) is your REAL first page load. I posted a data pager and image example above in my edit, and note how it on startup loads up the data - but additional buttons etc. if dropped on the page would NOT effect the display of pictures since that code to load/get the data ONLY occurs on startup.